# Download file after time from page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have an exe url that i want to download after 2 sec from page load: like this:

```
    var handle = 0;
    function Download() {
        window.location = "exeUrl";
        clearInterval(handle);
    }
    $(document).ready(function () {
        handle = setTimeout('Download()', 5000);            
    });
```

**NOW**: My problem is window.location will reload the page and download function will be recall?

Comment: why not to use window.open instead of window.location to rely on current page ???

Comment: lets consider this page as my download page

Comment: what is ur server side technology asp.net or php or what ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
window.location.href = "exeUrl";
```

instead.

Also,

```
setTimeout(Download, 2000);
```

is preferred to:

```
setTimeout('Download()', 2000);
```

Comment: No, function download is still call

Comment: Oh, I see. So the browser opens the `.exe` file and *reloads* the previous page (since an `.exe` file does not have a graphical representation for the browser to render), thus re-initiating the download?!

Comment: not exactly, the current page will be reloaded, so page load will be called again

Comment: @Hiyasat The `.exe` file is never requested? (If yes, then I think we already agree :) )

Comment: No :) the exe file will be called to download every 5sec that is the problem

Comment: my problem was the the exe url was empty :):) so agree with all you say +1 :)

Comment: Hiyasat Yup, that would probably cause some confusion :)

Answer (score 1):

maybe something like

```
function Download() {
    window.open("exeUrl");
    clearInterval(handle);
}
```

popup blocker will interfere here :(

Or you could add something like

```
function Download() {
  var ifr = document.createElement('iframe');
  ifr.src='exeUrl';
  ifr.style.width = '1px';
  ifr.style.height = '1px';
  ifr.style.border= 'none';
  ifr.style.position= 'absolute';ifr.style.margin= '-20px -20px';
  document.body.appendChild(ifr);
  clearInterval(handle);
}
```

Comment: i know, but this is my download page, i dont want any popup

Comment: added another method to my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
  var handle = false;
    function Download() {
        if(handle)return;
        handle=true;window.location = "exeUrl";
    }
    $(document).ready(function () {
        setTimeout('Download()', 5000);            
    });
```

that should work :)